# How to get a list of IdentityUsers and their Roles at the same time?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, roles, asp.net-core-identity

Chat message model:

```
public class ChatMessage
{
    [Key] public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required] public string Content { get; set; }
    [Required] public DateTime TimePosted { get; set; }

    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
    [Required, ForeignKey("authorId")] public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to get a list of chat messages from a given day while knowing if their author is in the role "Voice":

```
var messages = await dbContext.ChatMessages.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(chm => chm.TimePosted.Date == someDateTime.Date).OrderBy(chm => chm.TimePosted)
    .ToListAsync();

var result = new List<Tuple<ChatMessage, bool>> { };
foreach(var m in messages)
    result.Add(Tuple.Create(m, await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(Author, "Voice")));
```

As far as I can tell this will send to the database **as many queries as there are chat messages to fetch**, which seems obnoxious, because this should be done in only one query, shouldn't it? Or at least, a constant number of queries, but not linear.

Am I doing this wrong? If yes, how should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `Include` the `ApplicationUser` and `Claims` tables and do this all in the query.

I haven't fully tested this, but something along the lines of:

```
dbContext.ChatMessages
    .Include(i => i.Author)
    .Include(i => i.Author.Claims)
    .Where(w => w.Author.Claims.Any(a => a.ClaimType == ClaimTypes.Role 
                                         && a.ClaimValue == "Voice"));
```

Comment: Tried that, sadly, there doesnt seem to be any navigation property on IdentityUser like Claims or Roles

Comment: What's your `ApplicationUser` look like?

Comment: It only contains one irrelevant to this problem index: `public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser { public List<ReplayPlayer> gamesPlayed { get; set; } }`

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.1#add-identityuser-poco-navigation-properties) should help explain the missing `Claims` and `Roles` properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I currently have. UNTESTED, but doesnt seem to give out compilation errors:

```
string voiceRoleId = (await roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Voice")).Id;
var result = await dbContext.ChatMessages.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(chm => chm.TimePosted.Date == someDateTime.Date).OrderBy(chm => chm.TimePosted)
    .GroupJoin(
        dbContext.UserRoles.Where(ur => ur.RoleId == voiceRoleId),
        chm => chm.AuthorId, r => r.UserId,
        (chm, rs) => new { Message = chm, IsVoice = rs.Any() }
    ).ToListAsync();
```

This is... somewhat amazing. I thought the task would be simpler than 8 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach seems to come from @Kirk Larkin's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193549/how-to-get-a-list-of-identityusers-and-their-roles-at-the-same-time#comment91348886_52194364), which I'm converting to an answer because it is more visible than a comment and because comments may go away anytime.

He linked this docs page: [Migrate authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core 2.0#Add IdentityUser POCO navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.1#add-identityuser-poco-navigation-properties), which says:

> The Entity Framework (EF) Core navigation properties of the base
>   IdentityUser POCO (Plain Old CLR Object) have been removed. If your
>   1.x project used these properties, manually add them back to the 2.0 project: C#
>
> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Navigation property for the roles this user belongs to.
> /// </summary>
> public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<int>> Roles { get; } = new List<IdentityUserRole<int>>();
>
> /// <summary>
> /// Navigation property for the claims this user possesses.
> /// </summary>
> public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<int>> Claims { get; } = new List<IdentityUserClaim<int>>();
>
> /// <summary>
> /// Navigation property for this users login accounts.
> /// </summary>
> public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin<int>> Logins { get; } = new List<IdentityUserLogin<int>>();
> ```
>
> To prevent duplicate foreign keys when running EF Core Migrations, add
>   the following to your IdentityDbContext class' OnModelCreating method
>   (after the base.OnModelCreating(); call): C#
>
> ```
> protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
> {
>     base.OnModelCreating(builder);
>     // Customize the ASP.NET Core Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
>     // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Core Identity table names and more.
>     // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
>
>     builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
>         .HasMany(e => e.Claims)
>         .WithOne()
>         .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
>         .IsRequired()
>         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
>
>     builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
>         .HasMany(e => e.Logins)
>         .WithOne()
>         .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
>         .IsRequired()
>         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
>
>     builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
>         .HasMany(e => e.Roles)
>         .WithOne()
>         .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
>         .IsRequired()
>         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
> }
> ```

Once these steps are done, I believe writing the correct query should become as trivial as a single `Include` statement. Brain compiled code below:

```
var usersAndRoles = await dbContext.ChatMessages.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(msg => msg.Author).ThenInclude(author => author.Roles)
    .Select(msg => new { Message = msg, IsVoice = msg.Author.Roles.Contains("Voice") })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: That gets you the join table entity, but not the actual roles. `author.Roles` is an `IdentityUserRole`. Which doesn't have further navigation.